# Spring Data JPA. How to get only a list of IDs from findAll() method

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, specifications, criteria-api

I have a very complicated model. Entity has a lot relationship and so on.

I try to use Spring Data JPA and I prepared a repository.

but when I invoke a method findAll() with specification for the object a have a performance issue because objects are very big. I know that because when I invoke a method like this:

```
@Query(value = "select id, name from Customer ")
List<Object[]> myFindCustomerIds();
```

I didn't have any problems with performance.

But when I invoke

```
List<Customer> findAll();
```

I had a big problem with performance.

The problem is that I need to invoke findAll method with Specifications for Customer that is why I cannot use method which returns a list of arrays of objects.

How do I write a method to find all customers with specifications for the `Customer` entity but which returns only IDs.

like this:

```
List<Long> findAll(Specification<Customer> spec);
```

- I cannot use in this case pagination.

Please help.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what FetchType.LAZY was intended to solve.

Comment: It is better but still there is 10 - 15 second. From find all with query I have result in 1-2 second. It is possible to solve this problem using Spring Data. It means get value only from particular column  instead of all object?

Comment: I can't imagine how retrieving a whole row would be significantly slower than a single column.  Your database schema terrifies me!  But fixing it is probably out of the question I assume. Hopefully someone else will answer. Spring JPA is incredibly flexible and I'd think you could do this easily with a custom @Query. But I've never done it personally

Comment: Look, this is not a problem with database. Can you imagine that have you for instance some proxy between your application and your database. Do you see the diffrent when you want transfer a sparse object for example with two fields and when you want to transfer a object with many relationship and you cannot use a lazy fetching? This is the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved the problem.

(As a result we will have a sparse Customer object only with id and name)

### Define their own repository:

```java
public interface SparseCustomerRepository {
    List<Customer> findAllWithNameOnly(Specification<Customer> spec);
}
```

### And an implementation (remember about suffix - Impl as default)

```java
@Service
public class SparseCustomerRepositoryImpl implements SparseCustomerRepository {
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public SparseCustomerRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAllWithNameOnly(Specification<Customer> spec) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> tupleQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
        Root<Customer> root = tupleQuery.from(Customer.class);
        tupleQuery.multiselect(getSelection(root, Customer_.id),
                getSelection(root, Customer_.name));
        if (spec != null) {
            tupleQuery.where(spec.toPredicate(root, tupleQuery, criteriaBuilder));
        }

        List<Tuple> CustomerNames = entityManager.createQuery(tupleQuery).getResultList();
        return createEntitiesFromTuples(CustomerNames);
    }

    private Selection<?> getSelection(Root<Customer> root,
            SingularAttribute<Customer, ?> attribute) {
        return root.get(attribute).alias(attribute.getName());
    }

    private List<Customer> createEntitiesFromTuples(List<Tuple> CustomerNames) {
        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Tuple customer : CustomerNames) {
            Customer c = new Customer();
            c.setId(customer.get(Customer_.id.getName(), Long.class));
            c.setName(customer.get(Customer_.name.getName(), String.class));
            c.add(customer);
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 64):

Why not using the `@Query` annotation?

```
@Query("select p.id from #{#entityName} p")
List<Long> getAllIds();
```

The only disadvantage I see is when the attribute `id` changes, but since this is a very common name and unlikely to change (id = primary key), this should be ok.

Comment: or just `@Query("select id from #{#entityName}")`

Comment: does it work with specification?

Comment: *@Emil Terman* No. Everything in the *@Query* annotation **is** the SQL query that will be executed, therefore whatever SQL your specification is producing, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 30):

This is now supported by Spring Data using [Projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

```
interface SparseCustomer {  

  String getId(); 

  String getName();  
}
```

Than in your `Customer` repository

```
List<SparseCustomer> findAll(Specification<Customer> spec);
```

**EDIT:**
As noted by Radouane ROUFID Projections with Specifications currently doesn't work beacuse of [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1033).

But you can use [specification-with-projection](https://github.com/pramoth/specification-with-projection) library which workarounds this Spring Data Jpa deficiency.

Comment: Does this actually work for this use case? It seems java can't distinguish between this and the original method in JpaSpecificationExecutor<OriginalEntity> extended by the repository and I don't know which name to give the method instead.

Comment: Projections does not work using specifications.  `JpaSpecificationExecutor` only return a List typed with the aggregated root managed by the repository ( `List<T> findAll(Specification<T> var1);` )

Comment: Specification with Projection now is supported -> in Spring Data 3.0.0 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1378#issuecomment-1103534041

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) does not work with [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications).  `JpaSpecificationExecutor` return only a List typed with the aggregated root managed by the repository ( `List<T> findAll(Specification<T> var1);` )

An actual workaround is to use Tuple. Example :

```
    @Override
    public <D> D findOne(Projections<DOMAIN> projections, Specification<DOMAIN> specification, SingleTupleMapper<D> tupleMapper) {
        Tuple tuple = this.getTupleQuery(projections, specification).getSingleResult();
        return tupleMapper.map(tuple);
    }

    @Override
    public <D extends Dto<ID>> List<D> findAll(Projections<DOMAIN> projections, Specification<DOMAIN> specification, TupleMapper<D> tupleMapper) {
        List<Tuple> tupleList = this.getTupleQuery(projections, specification).getResultList();
        return tupleMapper.map(tupleList);
    }

    private TypedQuery<Tuple> getTupleQuery(Projections<DOMAIN> projections, Specification<DOMAIN> specification) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createTupleQuery();

        Root<DOMAIN> root = query.from((Class<DOMAIN>) domainClass);

        query.multiselect(projections.project(root));
        query.where(specification.toPredicate(root, query, cb));

        return entityManager.createQuery(query);
    }
```

where `Projections` is a functional interface for root projection.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Projections<D> {

    List<Selection<?>> project(Root<D> root);

}
```

`SingleTupleMapper` and `TupleMapper` are used to map the `TupleQuery` result to the Object you want to return.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SingleTupleMapper<D> {

    D map(Tuple tuple);
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface TupleMapper<D> {

    List<D> map(List<Tuple> tuples);

}
```

### Example of use :

```
        Projections<User> userProjections = (root) -> Arrays.asList(
                root.get(User_.uid).alias(User_.uid.getName()),
                root.get(User_.active).alias(User_.active.getName()),
                root.get(User_.userProvider).alias(User_.userProvider.getName()),
                root.join(User_.profile).get(Profile_.firstName).alias(Profile_.firstName.getName()),
                root.join(User_.profile).get(Profile_.lastName).alias(Profile_.lastName.getName()),
                root.join(User_.profile).get(Profile_.picture).alias(Profile_.picture.getName()),
                root.join(User_.profile).get(Profile_.gender).alias(Profile_.gender.getName())
        );

        Specification<User> userSpecification = UserSpecifications.withUid(userUid);

        SingleTupleMapper<BasicUserDto> singleMapper = tuple -> {

            BasicUserDto basicUserDto = new BasicUserDto();

            basicUserDto.setUid(tuple.get(User_.uid.getName(), String.class));
            basicUserDto.setActive(tuple.get(User_.active.getName(), Boolean.class));
            basicUserDto.setUserProvider(tuple.get(User_.userProvider.getName(), UserProvider.class));
            basicUserDto.setFirstName(tuple.get(Profile_.firstName.getName(), String.class));
            basicUserDto.setLastName(tuple.get(Profile_.lastName.getName(), String.class));
            basicUserDto.setPicture(tuple.get(Profile_.picture.getName(), String.class));
            basicUserDto.setGender(tuple.get(Profile_.gender.getName(), Gender.class));

            return basicUserDto;
        };

        BasicUserDto basicUser = findOne(userProjections, userSpecification, singleMapper);
```

I hope it helps.