# Load property of entity using spring-data-jpa query methods

Tags: java, spring, jpa

For example, I have entity `User` with fields `id`, `active` and 10 more.
How could I get all active Users? Easy:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<User> findAllByActiveTrue();
}
```

How could I load list of `id` of active users? I need a `@Query` annotation to write JPQL by myself, like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Query("select u.id from User u where u.active = true")
    List<Integer> fetchActiveUsersIds();
}
```

**My question is**: could I name somehow a method to avoid writing JQPL by myself, like in first case?

**UPDATE**

I need something like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    List<Integer> findAll_Id_ByActiveTrue();
}
```

Comment: The name of the method is given by the interface. If you change the name it will change nothing.

Comment: @RomanC I mean the name, that generates JPA query, like in first code example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331767/spring-data-jpa-how-to-get-only-a-list-of-ids-from-findall-method

Comment: @leeor That's not about what I want. No, that question looks similar to mine, but solution is much more verbose than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible. The main purpose of `Repository`is to manage persistence of *Domain Classes*. It doesn't manage the properties independently. In the [Spring Data Repositories documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#repositories) you can find a list of the methods available for `CrudRepository`.

You can compose your query using [property extensions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.x/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions) but it always returns the *domain class* for non aggregated methods.

For the specific use case you mention you'll need to use the `@Query` annotation.