# Is it possible to perform group by with specific columns in Spring Data Jpa Specification?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have functionality which uses RSQL (I use [this](https://github.com/perplexhub/rsql-jpa-specification) library) and Specification to make a filter call with where clauses to the db.

The model I query is quite simple: it just contains a bunch of properties without any relationships with other models.

The repository (notice that I use *JpaSpecificationExecutor*):

```java
public interface BaseRepository<M extends BaseModel> extends JpaRepository<M, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<M>{

}
```

So I retrieve filter conditions as a string (I get them on runtime) then just create a new specification which will be used to generate the result sql query with where clauses.

In the service I make a call to the repository method *findAll* with a Specificator:

```java
String filter = "createdDate > 2019-09-04T11:52:59.449";
return repository.findAll(toSpecification(filter), pageable).getContent();
```

Now I need to add new functionality which allows to group by some specific fields which I also get on runtime thus I don't know what fields exactly will be used for this.

So I've managed to add group by section to the result sql query by creating a new specification and combining it with the original one:

```java
String filter = "createdDate > 2019-09-04T11:52:59.449";

Specification<M> groupBySpec = new Specification<M>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<M> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

                List<Expression<?>> groupByParams = new ArrayList<>();

                groupByParams.add(root.get("param1"));
                groupByParams.add(root.get("param2"));

                query.groupBy(groupByParams);

                // Here I try to select specific columns
                query.multiselect(root.get("column1"), root.get("column2")).distinct(true);

                return query.getGroupRestriction();
            }
        };


return repository.findAll(groupBySpec.and(toSpecification(filter)), pageable).getContent();
```

But I get a sql exception `ERROR: column "columnName" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

The result of this because it actually selects all the columns and just ignores my `query.multiselect`.

I've tried to implement it using just Criteria Api without JPA Specification like this:

```java
public List<Object[]> getAllWithSpecific(){

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
          CriteriaQuery<Object[]> q = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
          Root<Model> c = q.from(Model.class);


        List<Expression<?>> groupByParams = new ArrayList<>();

        groupByParams.add(c.get("column1"));
        groupByParams.add(c.get("column2"));

        q.groupBy(groupByParams);
          q.select(cb.array(c.get("column1"), c.get("column2"), cb.count(q.from(Model.class))));

          return em.createQuery(q).getResultList();

    }
```

And it actually worked, it selected just what I need. But I can't just use it that way because I need this *group by* functionality to work in combination with filter, pagination functionality I described earlier.

Since JpaRepository works in the terms of the given model, I don't know how to say to it "grab only columns I need, **not the whole model**"

Also I've tried to add a method to the jpa repository annoted with `@Query("actual jpql query")` where I can describe what to select:

```java
@Query("select m.column1, m.column2, count(*) from Model m group by m.column1, m.column2")
    List<Object[]> customMethod();
```

And it works too. So now it understands that I need to grab only specific columns even though it still works in the terms of the same model.

I also know about *projections* which is actually an interface where I can define  columns to select and use it in the repo like this: `List<Projection> findAll()`.
But that's not my case as well as using `@Query` because I retrieve columns to select\group by during runtime, so it's kinda dynamic, not static.

**To summarize**: is possible to select specific columns using Jpa Specifications without adding new classes which would describe what to select (that's how `@Query` works, it just gets everything from jpql query without any additional classes\interfaces and it's fine). Maybe I need to override a jpa repo's method `findAll` to return `List<Object[]>` just as it works with `@Query` and pure Criteria Api?

Comment: can you add your Model class in the post.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331767/spring-data-jpa-how-to-get-only-a-list-of-ids-from-findall-method

Comment: Just like I mentioned in the question it's quite simple and contains just a bunch of String/Long/Date properties without any relations with other models.

Comment: @JensSchauder this question is not the same problem, because I don't know which fields to select till actual call and I've described it in my question. So I'm not sure that this is 100% duplicate.

Comment: What makes you think that you can do what is impossible when you know the fields at compile time becomes possible when you only know it at runtime?
Specifications are where clauses.